# Download files stored in AWS S3 from Laravel Nova results in bug

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-nova

We are using Nova package for our admin backend inside our Laravel App. All files and images are stored in the AWS S3 bucket.

After trying to download a file from Nova, the download begins with the name download.json and Server Error message.

Files are stored correctly in S3, I can check it manually, also the path to them inside S3 is correctly stored in the database.

Here is the code we use to create a download field in Nova

```
                ->download(function(){
                    return Storage::disk('s3')->download($this->name);
                })
                ->onlyOnDetail()
```

$this->name holds the path inside the s3 bucket.

config/filesystems.php is also defined:

```
'disks' => [
         ...
        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        ],
```

Nova documentation did not helped me on this problem. Any input would be really helpful.

**UPDATE:** 
The problem was not in code but in Configuration. 
Without changing the configuration the following code did help:

```
Text::make('File/Document', function() {
                $linkToFile = Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl($this->name, now()->addMinutes(1));
                return '<a href="' . $linkToFile . '" target="_blank">Download file</a>';
            })
                ->asHtml(),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to see any issue without seeing the complete function, but make sure your name property `$this->name` has the same value as your remote file 'key' as shown in your Amazon s3 bucket.

Also, make sure the your `.env` file is correct and contains the following value:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your_access_key
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your_secret_access_key
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=your_default_region
AWS_BUCKET=your_bucket_name
AWS_URL=your_url #if applicable
```

Hope this makes sense.

---

Edit: One more thing, in `filesystem.php`, this line:

```
  'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
```

was changed in Laravel 6.x according to [this bug](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/5267) and became:

```
  'endpoint' => env('AWS_URL'),
```

Comment: Thank you LobsterBaz. I changed 'URL' to 'endpoint' but I do not see any change. At this point and after a lot of tests I am thinking it is more a configurational problem than a Code problem.